# Ubuntu 16.04 - Wireless xbox 360 controller not detected by ubuntu/reciever

Tags: 16.04, wireless

Writing the command lsusb gives me:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 045e:02a9 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 064e:3410 Suyin Corp.
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 413c:3016 Dell Computer Corp. Optical 5-Button Wheel Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Where the following line is the microsoft PC wireless gaming reciever:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 045e:02a9 Microsoft Corp.
```

When I enter the command sudo xboxdrv, I get the following:

```
> xboxdrv 0.8.5 - http://pingus.seul.org/~grumbel/xboxdrv/  Copyright ©
> 2008-2011 Ingo Ruhnke <grumbel@gmx.de>  Licensed under GNU GPL version
> 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>  This program comes with
> ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  This is free software, and you are welcome to
> redistribute it under certain  conditions; see the file COPYING for
> details. 
> 
> 
> -- [ ERROR ] ------------------------------------------------------ No Xbox or Xbox360 controller found
```

Comment: Please comment if I should provide more information

Answer (score 2):

If you, like me, bought a damn cheap fake adapter, I think this will help you:

```
sudo xboxdrv --device-by-id 045e: 02a9 --type xbox360-wireless -l 6
```

How to make a launch without `sudo` I have not figured out yet. I think it is necessary to give the rights to start the user.

Perhaps, instead of `045e:02a9`, you need to substitute your value. You can recognize it with the `lsusb` command.